# How to solve a polynomial expression in python3.5?

Tags: python-3.5

```
from __future__ import division
import math
from sympy import *
d=symbol('d')
x=solve(d**2 - 224*d + 400)
print(x)
```

Hi,I'm new to python.I just tried to solve a polynomial expression using symPy,but got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Windows/System32/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    d=symbol('d')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Someone pls help me out with the correct function.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capitalize Symbol and try again.

Comment: I'm getting an error again.     
    NameError: name 'symplify' is not defined.                                               
Is there anyother way.

Comment: with that correction I can run the code on both Python 3.4.3 and Python 2.7.6, and both get me the output `[-4*sqrt(759) + 112, 4*sqrt(759) + 112]`.

Does the error message say symplify or simplify?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,I got that error when I tried to use symplify() instead of solve().now I get the same output as yours,but I expect 1.8 to display..ie the evaluation of d from          d**2 - 224d + 400 must yield d=1.8.  Shouldn't I use solve() for such evaluation...if so pls Suggest any other way to get the result

Comment: You can use the `N` function to evaluate expressions. Of course solve returns a list of expressions, so you need to process the list in some way (for example a for loop). Shortest solution I have (in python3) is changing the print line to `print(list(map(N,x)))`. This basically says to python, take the list `x`, apply the function `N` to each of its elements (that's what `map` does), and then form a new `list` out of the results and `print` it.

in python 2 it'd be `print map(N,x)`

Answer (score 2):

You're sure you are running python3, and your script is not named something that conflicts with any other modules?  Do you have a file named sympy.py in your script's directory? (You shouldn't)

I never use import *, you never know what kind of namespace errors you'll run into.  This code works 100% for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
import sympy

d = sympy.Symbol('d')
x = sympy.solve(d**2 - 224*d + 400)
print(x)  # Prints [-4*sqrt(759) + 112, 4*sqrt(759) + 112]

x = sympy.solve(d - 10)
print(x)  # Prints 10
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,I got that error when I tried to use symplify() instead of solve().now I get the output like[-4*sqrt(759) + 112, 4*sqrt(759) + 112].But I need   d**2 - 224d + 400 to yield d=1.8.  Shouldn't I use solve() for such evaluation...if so pls Suggest any other way to get the result

Comment: I'm afraid the error is in your math then. sympy.solve() is returning the correct result. To confirm, you are expecting d^2 - 224*d + 400 = 0 to resolve to d = 1.8?  If you substitute 1.8 for d, you will get 0.04.

Comment: Also, if you will be doing this frequently, I highly recommend spending some time in the [sympy docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) or checking out the book *Doing Math With Python*

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble putting code in comments. I have edited my example code to show you how sympy.solve() returns the single correct solution when it is able.

Answer (score 0):

try with `d = Symbol('d')`. Doing `symbol('d')` you are trying to use the `symbol` sub-module as a function which is invalid. Also as you are in python 3 you don't need that future import

Comment: I'm getting an error again. NameError: name 'symplify' is not defined. Is there anyother way.

Comment: that is weird, with only that modification it work for me